# React: Form submit must be clicked twice to set context globally using useContext

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, use-context

React Beginner here. I'm building a login form in React using jwt, axios and useContext. After being authorized from the backend, I store the data in the global context using AuthProvider and redirect to home page. the home page first checks for authorization and navigates to login on unauthorized access. However even after updating the auth (useState) on login, I still get a false value on the first click and get sent back to login even if authed. I've tried useEffects everywhere but to no avail. Code below

**AuthProvider.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { createContext } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext();
export default AuthContext

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const [authed, setAuthed] = useState(false);

    function login(user) {
        setUser(user);
        setAuthed(true);
    }
    
    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{login, user, authed}}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

**ProtectedRoute.jsx to /home**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import AuthContext from "../../context/AuthProvide";

const ProtectedRoute = ({children}) => {

    const {login, user, authed} = useContext(AuthContext);
    useEffect(() => {
        alert("HELLO")
        alert(authed)
        if (!authed) {
            return window.location.href = "/login";
        } else {
            return children
        }
    }, [authed, user, login]);
}
export default ProtectedRoute;
```

**Top part of Login.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useContext } from "react";
import "./login.css";
import AuthContext from "../../context/AuthProvide";

import { axios } from "../../context/axios";
const LOGIN = "/login";

const Login = () => {
    const {login, user, authed} = useContext(AuthContext);
    const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState("");

    const [userPassword, setUserPassword] = useState("");
    const [error, setError] = useState("");

    const errorRef = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
        
    }, [authed, user, login]);

    useEffect(() => {
        setError("");
    }, [userEmail, userPassword]);


    function handleUserEmail(event) {
        setUserEmail(event.target.value);
    }

    function handleUserPassword(event) {
        setUserPassword(event.target.value);
    }

    function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        axios.post(LOGIN, {
            email: userEmail,
            password: userPassword
        }).then(response => {
            if (response.data.error) {
                setError(response.data.error);
            } else {
                // this is supposed to be the one to set the user and auth to true
                login(response.data.token)
                alert(authed)
                    window.location.href = "/";
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            if (!error?.response) {
                setError("NO SERVER RESPONSE");
            } else if (error.response?.status === 400) {
                setError("MISSING USER NAME OR PASSWORD");
            } else if (error.response?.status === 401) {
                setError("UNAUTHORIZED ACCESS");
            } else {
                setError("UNKNOWN ERROR");
            }
            errorRef.current.focus();
        })
    }

    function resetForm() {
        setUserEmail("");
        setUserPassword("");
    }
  return (
  // the form is here
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issues

The main issue I see with the code is the use of `window.location.href`. When this is used it reloads the page. This remounts the entire app and any React state will be lost/reset unless it is being persisted to localStorage and used to initialize app state.

It is more common to use the navigation tools from `react-router-dom` (*I'm assuming this is the package being used, but the principle translates*) to issue the imperative and declarative navigation actions.

## Suggestions

The protected route component should either redirect to the login path or render the `children` prop if user is authorized. It passes the current location being accessed along in route state so user can be redirected back after successful authentication.

```
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { authed } = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (!authed) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" replace state={{ from: location }} />;
  } else {
    return children;
  }
};
```

The `Login` component should use the `useNavigate` hook to use the `navigate` function to redirect user to protected route once authenticated.

```
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Login = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { login, user, authed } = useContext(AuthContext);
  ...

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios.post(
      LOGIN,
      {
        email: userEmail,
        password: userPassword
      }
    )
      .then(response => {
        if (response.data.error) {
          setError(response.data.error);
        } else {
          login(response.data.token)
          navigate(state?.from?.pathname ?? "/", { replace: true });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        if (!error?.response) {
          setError("NO SERVER RESPONSE");
        } else if (error.response?.status === 400) {
          setError("MISSING USER NAME OR PASSWORD");
        } else if (error.response?.status === 401) {
          setError("UNAUTHORIZED ACCESS");
        } else {
          setError("UNKNOWN ERROR");
        }
        errorRef.current.focus();
      });
  }

  ...

  return (
    // the form is here
  );
}
```

Wrap the routes you want to protect with the `ProtectedRoute` component.

```
<AuthProvider>
  <Routes>
    ...
    <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    <Route
      path="/test"
      element={
        <ProtectedRoute>
          <h1>Protected Test Route</h1>
        </ProtectedRoute>
      }
    />
  </Routes>
</AuthProvider>
```

[image: Edit react-form-submit-must-be-clicked-twice-to-set-context-globally-using-usecontex]